# How to repeat an image vertically & horizontally?

Tags: html, css

Note : **repeat , repeat-x , repeat-y All of them don't work.**

So I have the following HTML & CSS code. I tried many ways but couldn't get to work. The image I want to repeat is XYZ.png.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>IOP</title>
<style>
body > header {
  background : url("a.png") repeat-x scroll 0 0 transparent;
  box-shadow : 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  width : 100% 
  position : relative;
  z-index : 10; 
  height: 57px; }
 #MAN {
  height:100%;
  padding : 30px 0 25px;
  background: url("XYZ.png") repeat ;
  }

</style>
</head>
<body>
<header></header>
<div id="man">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I even tried height:100% but that gave me a scroll bar.

Regards,
Netizen

Comment: Okay ! I actually don't care for those stuffs !

Comment: I cannot recreate your problem, what is the problem... the code you are using should work even in one of the oldest browser there is...

Comment: I'm running this in FF10 but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    <html>
<head>
<title>IOP</title>
<style>
body > header {
  background : url("a.png") repeat-x scroll 0 0 transparent;
  box-shadow : 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  width : 100% 
  position : relative;
  z-index : 10; 
  height: 57px; }
 #MAN {
  height:500px;
  width: 500px;
  padding : 30px 0 25px;
  background: url("XYZ.png") repeat ;
  }

</style>
</head>
<body>
<header></header>
<div id="man">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Add width and height to #MAN in pixels. Usualy height and width 100% will take size of its parrent. Try using wrapper div that will have widht 960px, and then inside wrapper every element with width 100% will take 960px width.
This is joust from my head didnt tested. Hope its ok. I havent wrote any html css for months now :(

Comment: I actually need this as a backbone of a mobile webapp that's why I wanted it to repeat. But this remains static. nvm still better than the previous result. Thanks !

Comment: Didn't help actually I'm getting a scroll bar. Anyways to do it without a scrollbar ?

Answer (score 0):

Allready tried if it's case-sensitive?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>IOP</title>
<style type="text/css">
body > header {
  background : url("a.png") repeat-x scroll 0 0 transparent;
  box-shadow : 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  width : 100% 
  position : relative;
  z-index : 10; 
  height: 57px; 
}
 /* case sensitive? ----> */ #man {
  height:100%;
  padding : 30px 0 25px;
  background: url("XYZ.png") repeat ;
  }

</style>
</head>
<body>
<header></header>
<div id="man">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do:

```
body { background: url(XYZ.png); }
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/Chb33/

Edit: You might also not be referencing your image properly. See my comment below.

Comment: It might be that you aren't referencing the image properly. If your CSS is in `www.yourdomain.com/css/style.css` and your images are in `www.yourdomain.com/images/XYZ.png`, you would need to reference it in your CSS as `../images/XYZ.png`.

Comment: Also, make sure that your file name in your CSS matches up with the file name; while CSS classes are case-insensitive, I don't think that file names are.

Comment: I'm workin on local host & everything is in 1 directory, so there's no need to worry